# Samba shows folders which are not accessible for a user

Tags: permissions, samba, ubuntu-mate

My Linux system has two users, and I configured samba on it, so some shared directories are accessible by both uses, and some are accessible by one of them.

The problem is when I access the computer from Windows clients and authenticate using the second user (with less permission), the folders which are not accessible are shown (although they are not browsable), how can I hide these folders from this user?

Here is a part of **/etc/samba/smb.conf** file:

```
[anonymous]
    path = /repo/samba/anonymous
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes
    valid users = user1, user2

[archive]
    path = /repo/samba/archive
    writeable = no
    browseable = yes
    valid users = user1, user2

[user1]
    path = /repo/samba/user1
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes
    valid users = user1

[user1-ro]
    path = /repo/samba/user1-ro
    writeable = no
    browseable = yes
    valid users = user1
```

When *user2* tries to access the server, they see *user1* and *user1-ro* folders too, and I want to hide these two for them.

I shall mention that the linux system runs **Ubuntu-MATE 16.04**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why but @techraf answer didn't work (although according to docs it should), but I found another solution and it worked. I've added

```
access based share enum = true
```

to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
hide unreadable = yes
```

to the share definitions in your config.

This is called "access-based enumeration" in SMB vernacular.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.